# How to change the color of the choosing item in android

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

About my  android app,the OnItemClickListener of ListView, I want to achieve when I click on one item ,this will be highlight or can be better:change color(red,blue or orange).and the rest will be the original color.I have check some course,I don't know how to realize,could anyone give me some guide or direction,I will be very appreciate about your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `android:listSelector="@drawable/your_image"` which meants not so good practice. Use XML for better gesture like `android:listSelector="@drawable/your_drawable_XML_file"`